# Changing letters of individual words within a string

Tags: java, string, split, char

I have to design a program that converts English into Pig Latin. I am having difficulty in converting all words contained within the input provided by the user to Pig Latin. With my current code, I achieve an output of:

> Input: This is not working
>   Output: histay is not workingay

While my desired output is:

> Input: This is not working.
>   Output: Histay ishay otnay orkingway

What am I doing wrong? I'm just looking for a push in the right direction.

```
public class piglatin {

    // A program designed to convert English words in to Pig Latin
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    char a, e, i, o, u, A, E, I, O, U, b;   
    String alphabet = "aAbBcCdDeEfFgGhHiIjJkKlLmMnNoOpPqQrRsStTuUvVwWxXyYzZ";

    Scanner word = new Scanner (System.in);         
    System.out.println("Please enter a word: ");                
    String incoming = word.nextLine();              
    System.out.println("Input: " + incoming);

    String newincoming = incoming.substring(1); 
    String newerincoming = incoming.substring(0,1);

    a = alphabet.charAt(0);
    e = alphabet.charAt(8);
    i = alphabet.charAt(16);
    o = alphabet.charAt(28);
    u = alphabet.charAt(40);
    A = alphabet.charAt(1);
    E = alphabet.charAt(9);
    I = alphabet.charAt(17);
    O = alphabet.charAt(29);
    U = alphabet.charAt(41);
    b = incoming.charAt(0);         

    if ((b == a) || (b == e) || (b == i) || (b == o) || (b == u) || (b == A) || (b == E) || (b == I) || (b == O) || (b == U)) {             
      System.out.println("Output: " + incoming + "hay");
    } else {  
      System.out.println("Output: " + newincoming + newerincoming + "ay");
    }
  }     
}
```

Comment: I feel like it would be easier to just use character constants in those declarations instead of using indexed lookups in an alphabet table.

Comment: Would the correct translation in to pig latin not be 'Isthay isway otnay orkingway'? What rules for translating to pig latin are you using?

Answer (score 3):

**Input:** This is not working
**Output:** his is not workingTay

You're reading in the entire line of text and applying the "pig latin" rule to the whole sentence.  This removes the first letter of the sentence and puts it at the end of the last word.

In order for this to work, you need to [`split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) the input string around spaces and apply the pig latin rules to each word in a loop.  I suggest creating a method that takes a String as input and does the pig latin conversion.  That way you just need to call the method on each word in the array returned by the `split` method.

Comment: I ended up splitting the string with a for loop and it solved my problem. Thank you